# Facebook Python SDK - GET events

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I am a newbie working with facebook python sdk. I found this file that enabled me to obtain event data from my facebook business page.
However, I am unable to fetch all of the fields I need. The missing field I am unable to obtain is the event videos. I am unable to retrieve the video source or video_url  for the video that was posted with the event.
I have tried many different variations of fields =
to no avail. Thank You

```
import facebook
import requests


def some_action(post):
    """ Here you might want to do something with each post. E.g. grab the
    post's message (post['message']) or the post's picture (post['picture']).
    In this implementation we just print the post's created time.
    """
    print(post["id"])


# You'll need an access token here to do anything.  You can get a temporary one
# here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
access_token = "My_Access_Token"


# Look at Bill Gates's profile for this example by using his Facebook id.
user = "397894520722082"

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')
print(graph.get_object(id=397894520722082,
fields='events{videos,id,category,name,description,cover,place,start_time,end_time,interested_count,attending_count,declined_count,event_times,comments}'))

# Wrap this block in a while loop so we can keep paginating requests until
# finished.
while True:
    try:
        # Perform some action on each post in the collection we receive from
        # Facebook.
        [some_action(post=post) for post in posts["data"]]
        # Attempt to make a request to the next page of data, if it exists.
        posts = requests.get(posts["paging"]["next"]).json()
    except KeyError:
        # When there are no more pages (['paging']['next']), break from the
        # loop and end the script.
        break
```

Comment: Neither https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ nor https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/ nor https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/ mention a `videos` edge for events.

Comment: _“video that was posted with the event”_ - is it actually directly tied to the event object itself? Or was it maybe posted on the event feed?